# Python return value from scheduled event

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I would like to get the value returned from a function called by a scheduled event. Below is a simple example of what I would like to do.

```
import time
import sched

schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def ret_this():
    return "This."

def schedthis():
    schedule.enter(2,1,ret_this, ())
    schedule.run()
    ## <- print returned value here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedthis()
```

I have tried many things like:

```
     schedule.enter(2,1,print ret_this, ())
```

or even:

```
    schedule.enter(2,1,ret = ret_this, ())
    schedule.run()
    print ret
```

Maybe some background will be necessary.

I would like to create a server that will listen for incoming connections(This is done.). When a connection is established a new thread will spawn and the socket will be parsed to that thread. On that thread the values sent to the server will be read and the server will judge what the client is trying to schedule. Once the server knows what the client wants it will schedule it.

If the user wants to view the information after the scheduled event has completed (Where this answer comes in) then it will wait until the event has ended and send the returned values to the client.

If not the the event will be scheduled and the client will receive "Done, farewell." and the connection will close. 

I call the programming gods, please could you help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually prety simple. You're returning something from the `ret_this` function, but you didn't put it anywhere, nor printing it!

**Edit**
*Please see this*

Turns out that the code i posted earlier only executes the function, not when it's run by the scheduler.
Since `scheduler.run` only runs a function without actually care about the value it returns, you'll have to store it somewhere to actually know when it's called.

For example, in a global variable:

```
def ret_this():
    global result
    result = "I'm called!"
```

Or just print it from `ret_this`:

```
def ret_this():
    print "This."
```

**Edit 2**
Another way to store it is writing it in a file. You can read it again later:

```py
def ret_this():
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('I am called!')

if __name__ = "__main__":
    schedthis()
    with open("output.txt", 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

If the execution was succesful, your file will contain `I am called!`. Else, it will be empty.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @alKid Thank you for the reply.Can anyone verify this answer?
When I try it a None value is printed. If i change the value returned by ret_this I still receive a None value. I tested this on python 2.7.4 and 3.3.2, maybe this works on your setup, because this would be the exact answer I am looking for.

Comment: Can we move to chat to discuss?

Comment: I'm testing it with python 2.7 and it works fine. Let me show you my full code in a second.

Comment: Seems like there's a mistake with my code, the one returning the function is `enter`, not `run`. I'll update my code.

Comment: I've updated my answer, my last one wasn't really correct. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I see what you mean. This is the answer to the current question so thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this is not the solution I'm looking for because I want to use multiple threads, The global value will be overwritten. If I print then the value is only printed on the server side.

Comment: Why don't you write it to a file? You can re-read it again when you need it. Added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not really happy with the most helpful answer yet,
saving the result to a file...

The result value could be saved into a mutable object e.g. I took a list to demonstrate the quick-and-dirty workaround:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sched, time

def foo(l:list[str]):

    # do some stuff...

    # append the result to the "return list"
    l.append("XXXX")

l:list[str] = list()

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(5, 1, foo, argument=(l,))
s.run()

if l:
    print(l[0])
```