# (Python Schedule) Change the times a scheduled event runs based on a csv file

Tags: python, csv, schedule

Note: I'm new to SO so apologies for any mistakes. I've done a couple of projects in Python before.

**The Program**

Essentially what the program does is notify a user about certain specific times based on a predefined timetable stored in a .csv file. The times change each day (which presents the problem I discuss later on). The csv file looks like this:

> Date,Day,Column1,Sunrise,Column3,Column4 etc
>
> 3,Monday,Value1,07:54,Value3,Value4

For this example, I'll use Sunrise throughout the walkthrough of the program.

I have a function called *get_today_times()* which is resposible for reading the csv and returning a list called time:

```
def get_today_times():
  #code goes here
  return times
```

There is then another function which gets the times from the above function:

```
def get_sunrise():
  times = get_today_times():
  sunrise_time = times[3]

  final_string = "Sunrise is at" + sunrise_time

  return sunrise_time, final_string
```

The above function is then called into a setup function:

```
def setup():
   sunrise_time, sunrise_string = get_sunrise()
   schedule_list = [sunrise_time, other variables following the same flow]
   output_list = [sunrise_string, other variables following the same flow] 

   return schedule_list, output_list
```

The data is then sent to discord using a webhook:

```
def sunrise_discord():
   notify_discord(final_string)
   #The notify_discord function sends it to a discord server using a webhook
```

All of the above is sheduled using *schedule* (https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) as such:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

   schedule_list, output_list = setup()

   schedule.every().day.at(schedule_list[0]).do(sunrise_discord)

   while True:
      schedule.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)
```

**The Problem**

From my understanding, the code runs from the start of the `if __name__` until the while loop which constantly runs.This therefore means that the times at which the discord messages are sent stays the same each day and results in a message such as:

> *(sent at 07:54)* Sunrise is at 08:13

*Schedule* also does not allow for a scheduled function to return a value such as:

```
#DOES NOT WORK
schedule_list, output_list = schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(setup)
```

I've attempted this:

> [Python return value from scheduled event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679798/python-return-value-from-scheduled-event)

but it didn't work for me :/ I think the difference between the above link and my scenario is that I need to directly change the times at which the events are scheduled to run.

I tried adding the following piece of code but it still didn't work:

```
while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

        if time.localtime().tm_hour == 00:
            if time.localtime().tm_min == 00:
                schedule_list, output_list = setup()
```

The above piece of code should re-run the *setup()* function at midnight and then re-assign the schedule_list and therefore the times at which it sends the discord messages but this did not work either :(

I've thought about scheduling the whole python program to run at a certain time each day. Once all of the scheduled events have taken place, kill the process / end the program and then restart the program the next day. I haven't really done any research into this yet, it's just been in the back of my mind. I think that it would work given that the program works correctly for the first day.

Any help / ideas or other input would be very much appreciated :)

Thank you,

Please note:

My code may not be the best but there are 21 messages being sent each day and I find that this way of coding is the easiest for me to work with. It is still in phase 1 Alpha and will most likely be changed before it is finished.

The question is how to re-define the schedule times, the rest of the code is only for context.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to extend schedule Job and Scheduler class.

Here is a examle how to re-schedule task on sunrise/sunset

```
import datetime
from astral import LocationInfo
from astral.sun import sun
from schedule import Scheduler as _Scheduler
from schedule import Job as _Job


def job(message="Task"):
    print("I'm working on:", message)


class Job(_Job):
    city = LocationInfo("London", "England", "Europe/London", 51.5, -0.116)
    last_sunrise = None
    last_sunset = None

    def __init__(self, interval, scheduler):
        super().__init__(interval, scheduler)

    def at_sunrise(self):
        s = sun(self.city.observer, date=self.next_run)
        self.last_sunrise = s["sunrise"]
        return self.at(self.last_sunrise.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

    def at_sunset(self):
        s = sun(self.city.observer, date=self.next_run)
        self.last_sunset = s["sunset"]
        return self.at(self.last_sunset.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

    def rescedule_astro(self):

       if self.last_sunset:
           self.at_sunset()

       if self.last_sunrise:
           self.at_sunrise()

    def _schedule_next_run(self):
        super()._schedule_next_run()
        self.rescedule_astro()
        
        
class Scheduler(_Scheduler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def every(self, interval=1):
       """ 
       Schedule a new periodic job.
       :param interval: A quantity of a certain time unit
       :return: An unconfigured :class:`Job <Job>`
       """
       job = Job(interval, self)
       return job


schedule = Scheduler()
schedule.every().friday.at_sunrise().do(job, message="Friday Sunrise")
schedule.every().day.at_sunset().do(job, message="Everyday Sunset")

print(schedule.jobs)
print(schedule.run_all())
print(schedule.jobs)
```